# Request to rate cookbook SQL diagram

Tags: database-design

I want to create a few applications (as a project for school) which will work on the same database. So I would be glad if you would point errors or what could be done better.

My database will be for cookbook apps and website mostly. It will store recipes, will allow adding a new one. As I think about it there will be an additional field in Recipe - IDUser and next table to it with name, pass, and email. In a web app, I will link it to the online shop so when I don't have the ingredient I can select a checkbox next to it and it will be added to the basket in amount what is closest to needed. I think it's called integration with the online shop. I also want to make servings so I can type 4 portions and recipe quantity will change to match it and there will be ofc default servings for example 4 portions/people.

I will link my database diagram which is in it's first version.[image]

Comment: A few minor aspects: 1. Is there an aggregate key on RecipeIngredient (assuming that you don't want to allow the same ingredient in the same recipe multiple times)? 2. How do you order the steps within one recipe (assuming that they have to be executed in some order)? 3. Are you sure that you want to use char and not varchar?

Comment: I'd query the assumption that `30` characters is the right default for most strings. E.g. how many recipes have you seen where they're described as `<cooking method> <main ingredient> with <secondary method> <secondary ingredient>`? I could see many of these exceeding the 30 character limit.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should use char or varchar, I think varchar is a bit slower when with char I will need more memory. In IngredientRecipe I will make IDIngredient field unique. If you look for step I could add an additional field like StepNumber but I think better idea is to sort it by ID but than what will be faster - reading single field or sorting like 5 elements.

Comment: And as for secondary method and secondary ingredient is an interesting option, like if you don't have wine use vinegar and you can select one or another to add to shopping basket. I have to think about logic how to do it, thanks.